# Expository material on the Gromov-Lawson surgery theorem

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, curvature, surgery-theory

I am looking for an expository text on the paper *"The classification of simply connected
manifolds of positive scalar curvature"* by Gromov and Lawson, in particular on the proof of Theorem A.

Comment: What about https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06311?

Comment: For a first overview of the proof, https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9781400865215-010/html might be more suitable, or https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.1245. Our paper that skupers linked is much more technical and detailed.

Comment: @JohannesEbert Thank you very much.